# Parameter 1 of constructor in package.Endpoint required a bean of type package.UserMapper that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a basic SpringBoot RestApi and now I created a endpoint, which returns me a list of all users in the db.

```
@RestController
public class UserEndpoint {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    public UserEndpoint(UserRepository userRepository, UserMapper userMapper) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<UserEntityDto> getAllUser() {
        List<UserEntity> entityList = userRepository.findAll();
        List<UserEntityDto> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(UserEntity userEntity : entityList) {
            list.add(userMapper.toDto(userEntity));
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I want to start the application i get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in com.spring.connectpostgresql.endpoint.UserEndpoint required a bean of type 'com.spring.connectpostgresql.mapper.UserMapper' that could not be found.
```

My UserMapper looks like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    UserEntity toEntity(UserEntityDto userEntityDto);
    UserEntityDto toDto(UserEntity userEntity);
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why I get this error and what it means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using MapStruct to generate the mappers, the proper way to generate the mappers as a Spring bean is to use `@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")`. Reference [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mapstruct#Injection)